# Difference in response from magento swagger and postman Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, url, postman, swagger

I have custom API in which I am retrieving customer balance as:

```
use Magento\CustomerBalance\Model\BalanceFactory;
........................
........................
$model = $this->balanceFactory->create()->setCustomerId($customerId)->loadByCustomer();
$customerBalance = $model->getAmount();
```

In postman request is send as:

> http://127.0.0.1/rest/V1/mymodule/request/R1

and output is correct *logged in* customer balance.

But when I test same API in Magento swagger UI, here the Curl appears is:

> curl -X POST
>   "http://127.0.0.1/index.php/rest/all/V1/mymodule/request/R1" -H
>   "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer
>   nbvkrjkewuiu398hds"

which has extra **index.php/rest/all/**

and from response the customer balance is shown as 0 always.

What is the reason of different output on testing same API in Default Swagger and then in Postman ?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it, we need to provide store code in url to get right response from swagger.

For Example in my case I provided it as:

http://127.0.0.1/swagger?store=default

This returns the output same as we get by Postman/Insomnia

Reference:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/generate-local.html#generate-a-full-rest-reference-locally

Please upvote if it helps you for the ease of upcoming readers.